# How to find DBCC events reported by sp_Blitz

Tags: sp-blitz

sp_Blitz reports:

```
Overall Events
7 DBCC events have taken place between Oct 14 2019  3:22PM and Nov 19 2019 12:24PM. This does not include CHECKDB and other usually benign DBCC events.
```

How do I find out what the 7 events were?

Thanks

Comment: You checked default trace? Read this link: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3445/using-the-sql-server-default-trace-to-audit-events/

Comment: I ran the 2 queries from the link related to DBCC. One returned no results and the other listed several DBCC CHECKDB commands. So neither helped to identify the 7 DBCC events identified by sp_Blitz. Thanks for your comment though.